# JSON get string with values only

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, jsonpath

Given json like this:

```
    {
       "key1":value1,
       "key2":value2
    }
```

Using rest-assured JsonPath

```
new JsonPath(json).getString("path")
```

it returns something like `[key1=value1, key2=value2]`
Is there a way to return only values like `[value1, value2]` ?

Comment: "*Given json like this: `["key1":value1, "key2"=value2]`*" that is not valid JSON.

Comment: I meant just any json {"key1":"value1", "key2"="value2"}

Comment: Then please correct your question (lets not introduce to question problems unrelated to main topic),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question topic is unrelated to your question. But, you can use simple function to achieve your goal.

```
function getValuesOnly(obj) {
 let values = []

 for(key in obj) {
   values.push(obj[key])
 }

 return values
}
```

above function will return the all the values within every key.Also you can use bellow function to get values even from nested objects.

```
function getValuesOnlyNested(obj) {
  let values = [];
  for (key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] !== "object") {
      values.push(obj[key]);
    } else {
      values = values.concat(getValuesOnlyNested(obj[key]));
    }
  }
  return values;
}
```